# How to convert an r datafile to csv without using R?

Tags: r, vba, csv

I am facing a weird task. I need to convert a datafile, which is in R to a csv file by using an automated vba script or a batch job. Installing R studio or a plug in for excel is not allowed due to compliance issues. Is this possible to do this conversion using a vba script and if yes, how? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no idea of the answer to this, but it might help others to know if these are `.rds` or `.RData` / `.rda` files.

Comment: Is it possible to install R itself?

Comment: Yes, R is a programming language like Python, Perl, PHP, etc. that is unrelated to any IDE and so is separately installed and can run at command line using built-in `Rscript` and VBA can run external commands with `Shell`. _Any_ text editor is enough to write R scripts. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) all these topics and return with a *specific* question.

Comment: @Parfait, OK! Yes, right! That was the idea I was looking for! Would you mind posting this as an answer? I will try it this evening

Comment: Another possibility is to use [RStudio Cloud](https://www.rstudio.com/products/cloud/) version which you would access from your web browser. Convert the file and download the .csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, R is an open source, programming language that is independent of any IDE like RStudio. Its installation includes terminal shells and command line tools such as `Rscript.exe`. VBA can run external command line using [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) or [Windows Script Host](https://ss64.com/vb/shell.html). R can even receive arguments from the command caller!

**R** *(receiving arguments)*

```r
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)   # RECEIVE ALL COMMAND LINE ARGS

var1 <- args[1]
var2 <- args[2]

cat(paste(
    "Hi! This line is from R and received", 
    var1, "and", var2, "from command line \n"
))
```

**Cmd/PowerShell/Bash/etc.** *(sending arguments)*

```
# if R bin folder is in PATH environment variable
Rscript "C:\path\to\my_script.R" "Stack" "Overflow"     

# if R bin folder is not in PATH environment variable
C:\path\to\R\bin\Rscript "C:\path\to\my_script.R" "Stack" "Overflow"
```

**VBA** *(replicating command line above)*

```vb
Sub Run_RScript()
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim var1 As String, var2 As String
    Dim Rcmd As String, output As String
    
    var1 = "" & "Stack" & ""       ' STRINGS REQUIRE DOUBLE QUOTES
    var2 = "" & "Overflow" & ""    ' STRINGS REQUIRE DOUBLE QUOTES

    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Rcmd = "Rscript C:\path\to\myScript.R " & var1 & " " & var2
    output = oShell.Exec(Rcmd).StdOut.ReadAll
    
    Debug.Print output             ' PRINT TO IMMEDIATE WINDOW (CTRL+G)
    
    Set oShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

```
Hi! This line is from R and received variables ( Stack and Overflow ) from command line
```